# Change HTML content inside a node with XSL 1.0

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I would like to change the HTML content of an XML node to replace some BBCode with HTML tags in XSL 1.0.

My XML looks like this :

```
<Article>
    <Title>Article test</Title>
    <Content>
        <![CDATA[<p>Lorem Ipsum :</p><p>"[[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet]] is a great tool !"</p>]]>
    </Content>
</Article>
```

I would like to replace "[[" by "`<em>`" and "]]" by "`</em>`".

My XSL looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"
    media-type="text/html"
    indent="yes"
    omit-xml-declaration="yes"
    encoding="ISO-8859-1"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Strict//FR"
    />
    <xsl:template match="/" >
<html>
    <head>
        <!--...-->
    </head>
    <body>
<xsl:for-each select="//Article[1]">
                        <h2><xsl:value-of select="Title"/></h2>
                        <div class="content"><xsl:apply-templates select="Content"/></div>
</xsl:for-each>
    </body>
</html>
    </xsl:template><!-- match=/ -->
    <xsl:template match="Content">
        <xsl:variable name="normaContenu"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" /></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="replacePatternStart"><![CDATA[<em>]]></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="replacePatternEnd"><![CDATA[</em>]]></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="contenuWithStartTags">
            <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$normaContenu" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'[['" />
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="string($replacePatternStart)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="string($contenuWithStartTags)" />
            <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="']]'" />
            <xsl:with-param name="by" select="string($replacePatternEnd)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template><!-- match=Content -->
    <xsl:template name="replace">
        <xsl:param name="text" />
        <xsl:param name="replace" />
        <xsl:param name="by" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
                <xsl:call-template name="replace">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template><!-- name=replace -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Problem : the "`<em>`" is, in fact "`&lt;em&gt;`".
How can I force XSL to preserve the characters as it is defined in the CDATA ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't easy to follow. The replace actually happens somewhere with <xsl:value-of select="..."/> - here use <xsl:value-of select="..." disable-output-escaping="yes"/> instead.

@Pierre Morin: the <em> tags might be escaped when inserted, so disable-output-escaping shows no effect. Different Browsers can differ in handling the transformation, there can by various mistakes. Try a small solution only containing the output and fit this in when it works. I suggest using a transformation engine like SaxonCE (free client side XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 engine, javascript) or libexslt (free server side XSLT 1.0 engine, written in c, widely used, e.g. php)
Another hint: Try not to apply starting and ending tags in different code. XSLT isn't build for that. You can works with elements without breaking them, but this takes some time getting the idea of XSLT. It's powerful, once you got it.
I don't know if this matches your needs, but put a $text in <em> can be as easy as

```
<xsl:template match="...">
  <em>  
    <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
  </em>  
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

The important part is in the `xsl:template match="Content"`.
It takes the "Content" node and replace all the "[[" and the "]]" and, then, print the result of the 2 replacing.

I tried to add `disable-output-escaping="yes"` in `<xsl:value-of select="$text" />` but nothing changed...

Comment: Really strange ! After a try on IE(6), it's working... Firefox 24 would be the problem ?